# Android get empty preference

Tags: android, static, nullpointerexception, preferences

I have a problem when I like getText of preference empty, I believe the problem is the static method but I understand

The logcat says `NullPointerException`

```
05-30 09:19:52.802: E/AndroidRuntime(20917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 09:19:52.802: E/AndroidRuntime(20917): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The error is in this line:

```
accountUsername.getText()
```

Obviously I referenced the preference typing:

```
private static EditTextPreference accountUserName;
accountPassword = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("password");
```

And then the line error

The reason of static method is that is called by another class.

The application shutdown automatically when method is called

Any help, please??

Thanks

Comment: You have not initialized accountUserName. You are initializing accountPassword. Just check once.

Comment: ...or give us some more code!

Comment: Sorry Copying, both fields are similar, but copiying to the post I copied wrong